# Local storage is adding a null object into my array

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I've created an 'add to favorites' functionality using local storage. When I add products from a product page they are added, stored, and displaying properly when I initially navigate to my favorites page. However, if I navigate back and forth within the browser or type in the favorites page URL directly, I'm receiving this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null

The line with the error is: id = item.id;

When investing the error I noticed that a null object has now been added to my array. I'm not sure why this null object is being added.

Here is the code for an individual product page where I'm adding it:

```
var debug = true; // Set to true to output message to the error console
$(document).ready(function() {
  var favs = favInit();
  var item = {
    id:   '{{ dynamic_page_hubdb_row.hs_id }}',
    name: '{{ dynamic_page_hubdb_row.hs_name }}',
    url:  '{{ dynamic_page_hubdb_row.image.url }}',
    path: '{{ request.path }}'
  }
  var isFav = isFavorite(item,favs);
  if (isFav){
    setAsFavorite();
    $('#addFavorite').hide();
    $('#addFavoriteStar').hide();
    $('#removeFavorite').show();
    $('#removeFavoriteStar').show();
  } else {
    removeAsFavorite(item);
    $('#addFavorite').show();
    $('#addFavoriteStar').show();
    $('#removeFavorite').hide();
    $('#removeFavoriteStar').hide();
  }
  $('#addFavorite, #addFavoriteStar').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (debug) { console.log('adding item as a favorite'); }

    // Update localStorage
    setAsFavorite(item);

    // Update class
    $('#itm{{ dynamic_page_hubdb_row.hs_id }}').addClass('isFavorite');
      $('#addFavorite').hide();
    $('#addFavoriteStar').hide();
    $('#removeFavorite').show();
    $('#removeFavoriteStar').show();

    // Trigger modal
    $('#myModal').modal('show');

    return false;
  });
  $('#removeFavorite, #removeFavoriteStar').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (debug) { console.log('removing item from favorites'); }

    // Update localStorage
    removeAsFavorite(item);

    // Update class
    $('#itm{{ dynamic_page_hubdb_row.hs_id }}').removeClass('isFavorite');
    $('#addFavorite').show();
    $('#addFavoriteStar').show();
    $('#removeFavorite').hide();
    $('#removeFavoriteStar').hide();

    return false;
  });
});

function favInit(){
  // Get the existing favorites from localStorage
  var favs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
  if (debug) { console.log('favInit-1 favorites: '+localStorage.getItem('favorites')); }
  // If localStorage.favorites doesn't exists, create an empty array
  if (favs != null && Array.isArray(favs) && favs.length){ } else {
    if (debug) { console.log('no favorites found in local storage. Creating an empty array'); }
    favs = new Array; // setup an empty array
    // Refresh local storage
    localStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(favs));
    // pull favs from local storage
    favs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
  }

  if (debug) { console.log('favInit-2 favorites: '); console.dir(favs); }

  return favs;
}

function isFavorite(item,favs){
  if (favs != null && favs.length){
    // Find the selected item in the favs array
    var test = favs.find(x => x.id === item.id);
    //var test = $.grep(favs, function(e){ return e.id == item.id; });
    if (test != null){
      if (debug) { console.log('item is already a favorite: '); console.dir(item); }
      return true;
    } else {
      if (debug) { console.log('item is not a favorite.'); }
      return false;
    }
  }
}

function setAsFavorite(item){
  var favs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
  favs.push(item);
  localStorage.setItem('favorites',JSON.stringify(favs));
  if (debug) { console.log('favInit-1 favorites: '+localStorage.getItem('favorites')); console.dir(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites'))) }
}

function removeAsFavorite(item){
  removeAsFavoriteByID(item.id)
}

function removeAsFavoriteByID(id){
  var favs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
  var idx = favs.findIndex(x => x.id === id);
  delete favs[idx];
  var favs = favs.filter(function (el) {
    return el != null;
  });
  if (debug) { console.log('removeAsFavorite: '+favs); }
  if (favs.length){
    //console.log('favs does have a length');
    localStorage.setItem('favorites',JSON.stringify(favs));
  } else {
    //console.log('favs has no length');
    localStorage.setItem('favorites',JSON.stringify(new Array));
  }
  if (debug) { console.log('favInit-1 favorites: '+localStorage.getItem('favorites')); console.dir(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites'))) }
}

if (debug){
  $('.product-ctas').append( '<a href="#" class="clearFavorites">clear favs</a>' );
  $('.product-ctas').on('click','.clearFavorites',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    localStorage.removeItem('favorites');
    alert('Favorites cleared');
    return false;
  });
}
```

Here is my code for the favorites page:

```
var debug = true; // Set to true to output message to the error console
$(document).ready(function() {
  var favs = favInit();
  displayFavorites('#favorites-list',favs);
});

function favInit(){
  // Get the existing favorites from localStorage
  var favs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
  if (debug) { console.log('favInit-1 favorites: '+localStorage.getItem('favorites')); }
  // If localStorage.favorites doesn't exists, create an empty array
  if (favs != null && Array.isArray(favs) && favs.length){ } else {
    if (debug) { console.log('no favorites found in local storage. Creating an empty array'); }
    favs = new Array; // setup an empty array
    // Refresh local storage
    localStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(favs));
    // pull favs from local storage
    favs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
  }

  if (debug) { console.log('favInit-2 favorites: '); console.dir(favs); }

  return favs;
}

function displayFavorites(containerID,array){
  var $list = $('<ul/>'), id, item, image, title;
  for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    item = array[i];
    if (debug) { console.log('item '+i+': '); console.dir(item); }

    id = item.id;

    $image = $('<a/>').attr('href',item.path).append( $('<img/>').attr('src',item.url).attr('title',item.name) );
    $title = $('<strong/>').append( $('<a/>').attr('href',item.path).text(item.name) );
    $list.append( $('<li/>').attr('id','itm'+id).append($image).append($title) );
  }
  $(containerID).html($list);
}

function removeAsFavoriteByID(id){
  var favs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
  var idx = favs.findIndex(x => x.id === id);
  delete favs[idx];
  var favs = favs.filter(function (el) {
    return el != null;
  });
  if (debug) { console.log('removeAsFavorite: '+favs); }
  if (favs.length){
    //console.log('favs does have a length');
    localStorage.setItem('favorites',JSON.stringify(favs));
  } else {
    //console.log('favs has no length');
    localStorage.setItem('favorites',JSON.stringify(new Array));
  }
  if (debug) { console.log('favInit-1 favorites: '+localStorage.getItem('favorites')); console.dir(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites'))) }
}
```

Comment: where are you adding it?

Comment: I'm adding it on the individual product pages. I've udated my question above with that code.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use `delete`, it will replace it with `null/undefined`

```js
var favs = [{}]

delete favs[0]

console.log(favs)
```

Use splice

```js
var favs = [{}]

favs.splice(0, 1)

console.log(favs)
```